# Threading.Thread.Sleep() throws unexpected exceptions

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, exception, concurrency

In a high-volume (1-2 million http requests daily) web application (a SCORM player), we have a queue to handle peak loads gracefully - at peak load, requests may need to wait 20-50 ms to get served, in a queue shared across application instances. That's the call to Sleep() in the code below. Strangely, the call of Sleep() occasionally (100-150 times a day) throws a null reference exception, which is NOT being caught by the try/catch. We're logging this to Application Insights.

- How can Sleep() throw this undocumented exception? Can Threding.Thread be null, or?
- How can a try/catch fail to catch the exception?

```json
{
   "Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
   "Data":[
      
   ],
   "InnerException":null,
   "TargetSite":"Void WaitInQueue(System.Guid, SCORM.LmsInstance)",
   "StackTrace":"   at SCORM.API.WaitInQueue(Guid key, LmsInstance instance) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\SCORM\\API.ashx.vb:line 57",
   "HelpLink":null,
   "Source":"SCORM",
   "HResult":-2147467261,
   "_typeTag":"NullReferenceException"
}
```

```vb
Private Shared Lock As New Object

Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim response As HttpResponse = context.Response
    response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Dim myLmsInstance As New LmsInstance With {
        .RequestData = New ApiRequestData(context.Request)
    }
    myLmsInstance.InitializeSessionData()

    Dim key As Guid = Guid.NewGuid
    MaintainQueue(True, key, myLmsInstance)
    WaitInQueue(key, myLmsInstance)
    myLmsInstance.HandleApiCall()
    MaintainQueue(False, key, myLmsInstance)
    response.Write(myLmsInstance.GetResponseData)
End Sub

Private Sub MaintainQueue(addToQueue As Boolean, key As Guid, instance As LmsInstance)
    SyncLock Lock
        If instance.SessionData IsNot Nothing Then
            If addToQueue Then
                instance.SessionData.RequestQueue.Add(key)
            Else
                instance.SessionData.RequestQueue.Remove(key)
            End If
            Dim NextInQueue = instance.SessionData.RequestQueue.FirstOrDefault
            If NextInQueue <> Guid.Empty Then
                instance.SessionData.NextInQueue = NextInQueue
            Else
                instance.SessionData.NextInQueue = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End SyncLock
End Sub

Private Sub WaitInQueue(key As Guid, instance As LmsInstance)
    If instance.SessionData IsNot Nothing Then
        Try
            Dim NextInQueue = instance.SessionData.NextInQueue
            While NextInQueue.HasValue AndAlso NextInQueue.Value <> key
                ' Sleep as briefly as possible. The default on a Windows server is 15 ms.
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
                NextInQueue = instance.SessionData.NextInQueue
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Serilog.Log.Logger.Warning(ex, "Exception in SCORM Player, WaitInQueue():  {@ex}", ex)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

The try/catch was added recently, expecting to handle the exception and give us logging. But the exception is still unhandled, the Logger.Warning() code is never reached.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess what is actually throwing is the line `NextInQueue = instance.SessionData.NextInQueue` which doesn't look like it has any locking/interlocking to prevent concurrency problems. You should probably have something there, although it's unclear what `SessionData` and `NextInQueue` do already? Another thought: you should probably be using `async` and `await Task.Delay` to avoid tying up a whole thread with each request.

Comment: Thank you for a super fast response!
I probably should have included more code. Instance is instantiated locally, and there is locking on that. I'll see if I can edit the post to include that code.

And yes, it does look like an option that the line number given in the exception is a few lines off, explaining why try/catch doesn't. do its job.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it (pending verification under high loads):

Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) was wrong, I was missing my Imports statement. I'm correcting this to the following:

Imports System.Threading

Thread.Sleep(1)

Comment: `Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)` should not be wrong. Both options point to the same namespace and function. Actually including more namespaces in a call is usually a way to remove ambiguity in calls, so I don't see how your edit can actually improve anything. Can you explain why you think this will solve the problem?